# How to get around creating a 'List' model in Laravel?

Tags: php, model, laravel

Seems like 'List' is a certain keyword for Laravel (or PHP itself, I'm not sure.. I'm new to Laravel).

I have a table in my database called `lists`. Within that table there's a field called `title`. Also, a table called `tasks`, with a `list_id` column referencing the `id` column from the `lists`, so what I'm doing for now is:

app/models/MyAppList.php

```
class MyAppList extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'lists';
    public function tasks() {
        return $this->hasMany('Task', 'list_id');
    }
}
```

app/models/Task.php

```
class Task extends Eloquent {
    public function myapplist()   {
        return $this->belongsTo('MyAppList');
    }
}
```

app/routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $v = Task::find(1);
    dd($v->myapplist()->lists('title'));
});
```

This outputs the title of the list that owns that task just fine.

I thought namespacing the model would work. The file would be `List.php`, the class would be `List`, inside the file `namespace MyApp;` and then:

app/routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $lists = MyApp\List::all()->lists('title');
    dd($lists);
});
```

But it doesn't work.

## EDIT 1:

To clariy, if I leave the word 'List' as the name of the file and the class and then I try:

app/routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $lists = List::all()->lists('title');

    dd($lists);
});
```

I get:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting '('
```

If I namespace the class `List`:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $lists = Mdl\List::all()->lists('title');

    dd($lists);
});
```

I get:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected 'List' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

Comment: And the error you get is?

Comment: List is indeed a PHP reserved keyword, which cannot be used as "constants, class names, function or method names". See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php for more info. Solution? Different class name, really no other way to do it. Some would say "ListModel" is fine but I would instead try to be more detailed about what this list is. SubscriptionList? UserList? etc.

Comment: @NathanLoding added edit 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution is to use different Eloquent class model name than List  as list is reserved keyword in PHP.