# Laravel model scope function names

Tags: laravel-5.1

While creating a scope function with name 'scopeList' in the Model to return a data collection (has select) laravel throws a T_List error. Can I know why?

My code:

```
namespace project1;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lookup extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('type','code','description','listorder');
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * List lookup entries for a given type
     *
     * @param $type
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function scopeEntries($query,$type){
        return $query->select('code','description')
            ->where('type',$type)->get();
    }
}
```

If instead of 'scopeEntries', I want to call it 'scopeList' I encounter an error.

Comment: Please share your code, that will make is easier to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212342/how-to-get-around-creating-a-list-model-in-laravel - answer

Comment: Thanks KolleY to remind me that 'list' is a reserved word. But in my code if  I seperate out the select(), then the 'scopeList' has no problem!

Comment: what do you mean by "seperate out select() "  ?

Comment: remove the select and maintain only the constraints in this function

Comment: scopeList should work in no way, as to use it you have to call Lookup::list().. wich will always fail due to syntax error.

Comment: It works when it is chained  such as Lookup::select(...,  ...,)->list();

Comment: well that's indeed working, but shouldn't in my oppinion... Seems like an php interpreter  issue. Calling list() statically generates a syntax error, but calling list on an object is working fine. Generally you can't define a function called list, but the QueryBuilders magic __call() method this will be transformed to a resulting call to scopeList() .... I'll investigate this further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98326/discussion-between-jude-and-shock-gone-wild).

Comment: Anyone who is more interested have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353400/php-using-language-constructs-in-combination-with-magic-methods