# PHP Using Language constructs in combination with magic methods

Tags: php

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350076/laravel-model-scope-function-names) made me curious about using language constructs in combination with PHP's magic methods. I have created a demo code:

```
<?php
class Testing {

    public function scopeList() {
        echo "scopeList";
    }

    public function __call($method, $parameters) {
        if($method == "list") {
            $this->scopeList();
        }
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters) {
        $instance = new static;
        call_user_func_array([$instance, $method], $parameters);
    }
}

//Testing::list();
$testing = new Testing();
$testing->list();
```

Why does `Testing::list()` throw a syntax error and `$testing->list()` does not?

Due to [php reserved keywords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) both should fail?

Comment: Though it works like this: `Testing::{'list'}();`

Comment: The entire question could be reduced to the last two paragraphs. There really isn't any point in reading through and comprehending that code sample.

Comment: @deceze maybe it could. But I think an example makes sense here for clarity ? I wanted to show, how the magic methods work in this example...

Comment: Not really. The issue is simple: `Foo::list()` is a syntax error, `$foo->list()` is not. It doesn't matter what Foo is or does and the issue has nothing at all to do with magic methods or anything else.

Comment: of course it has to do with magic methods. You can't even declare a function named list() because list  is reserved

Comment: Arguably so, but that doesn't change the nature of the problem, which is that `::list()` is caught as a syntax error and `->list()` isn't.

Comment: And I'd think in the end the answer pretty much boils down to: *PHP, sigh, amirite?!* ;)

Comment: Yeah, but: If I hadn'n the _call or __callStatic  the error would be: fatal error: Call to undefined method Testing::list() in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\laravel\test.php . So the magic methods are important here

Comment: Could you at least reduce  their implementation to be empty? `function __call() {} function __callStatic() {}` will do just fine to demonstrate the actual problem...

Comment: I am  sorry: but no. The code inside __callStatic will trigger __call()

Comment: This is actually an example from the laravel framework. It does the exact things like that when using query scopes.

Comment: fyi there is a PHP chatroom on SO here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php I would recommend asking there before reporting "bugs".

Comment: thank's did not know about that chatroom. I asked on IRC freenode #php channel... Is it likely to meet php core developers on that stackoverflow chatroom ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context sensitive identifiers are now supported for **PHP 7.0+** and your code would simply work. Updating your PHP would fix the issue.

This was the approved RFC that made the change: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/context_sensitive_lexer.

You can get more information about new features and breaking changes on the following (unofficial) PHP 7 reference: https://github.com/tpunt/PHP7-Reference#loosening-reserved-word-restrictions

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: thanks for your information ;)  Php 7.0 however is due to hosting restsrictions not yet a choice for me ( and possibly for many others, too). And as I said, I was aware of reserved keywords restrictions, but the case in the OP looked quite odd and not consistent to me.

Answer (score 4):

**Update PHP 7**

PHP 7 addressed the described behaviour and implemented a feature called *context sensitive lexer* as brought up by [marcio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34357447/171318).

Your code will simply work with PHP 7.

---

**Situation before PHP 7**

Syntax errors are thrown before PHP is even aware of the fact that a method is available through `__callStatic()`, it happens at parsing stage.

The behaviour you described seems to be a bug in the PHP parser, at least an inconsistency that should be described in the documentation.

I would [file a bug report](https://bugs.php.net/). Good catch!

---

Update: The OP has file a bug report which can be found here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71157

Comment: thank's for your input. I always had in mind that it could be a bug in the parser, but i didn't have the knowledge to be sure about that.

Comment: You are welcome! Again, good catch. Unfortunately the (PHP) programmer can't do anything here, except of avoiding to use reserverd keywords. Would like to hear the PHP core developer's opinion on that, I mean if they would go an fix it or say don't use `list` in that context.

Comment: Yeah, im interested in this kind of stuff ;) Otherwise i wouldn't research. I have filed a bug report, but only in case of 'documentation issues'. I think it's not a 'real' bug but rather an inconsistency.

Comment: Can you add the link to my answer?

Comment: In the bug report? Yeah of couse ;)

Comment: yeah.. but someone just copied that report.. and you linked in your answer... my original report was : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71158

Comment: Weird! I guess it has been copied because you just filed a documentation bug.

Comment: fyi there is a PHP chatroom on SO here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php I would recommend asking there before reporting "bugs".

Comment: @Danack While I would not say that the PHP chat room on Stackoverflow is the ultimate instance to ask before reporting a PHP bug, I agree that it would have been helpful in this case.

Comment: and well... i still think it is a bug for php versions below 7.0  ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's because reserved words,

if you replace `Testing::list();` with `call_user_func_array(['Testing', 'list'], []);` it works as expected.

Comment: i'm familiar with reserved words, that's why i posted that link to php documentation. But why does it fail if i call list() statically and it does not if I call list on an actual object? The __callStatic() magic method should handle this.

Comment: While it is indeed not an answer to the problem, I upvote this because it offers a workaround that might be interesting for others stumbling upon this.